# How to change entry point to a function with parameters of C program compiled with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I would like to pass a parameter to a function using the GNU ld linker entry point option.

The [ld's documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.35/ld/Entry-Point.html#Entry-Point) says:

> 3.4.1 Setting the Entry Point
>
> The first instruction to execute in a program is called the entry
> point. You can use the ENTRY linker script command to set the entry
> point. The argument is a symbol name:
>
> ENTRY(symbol)
>
> There are several ways to set the entry point. The linker will set the
> entry point by trying each of the following methods in order, and
> stopping when one of them succeeds:
>
> - the ‘-e’ entry command-line option;
> - the ENTRY(symbol) command in a linker script;
> - the value of a target-specific symbol, if it is defined; For many    targets this is start, but PE- and BeOS-based systems for example
>   check a list of possible entry symbols, matching the first one found.
> - the address of the first byte of the ‘.text’ section, if present;
> - The address 0.

But is not clear how to pass a parameter to the entry point.

This is a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int entry(int p)
{
    printf("%i \n", p);
    exit(0);
}
```

To compile I run:

```
gcc -nostartfiles -e entry entry.c -o entry
```

Output:

```
./entry 1
-836386416
```

It seems that the parameter is ignored.

Is it possible pass parameters to an entry point? All the sources I consulted do not pass parameters.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not use the normal `argc/argv` mechanism for passing parameters to a new process?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the C runtime to pass command-line arguments to the `main` function. The entry point, as opposed to `main`, doesn't accept any arguments (in the C language sense). The runtime fetches the arguments from and OS-specific place and passes them to `main`. You are not using the standard C runtime so you need to do your own fetching from an OS-specific place.

Comment: @gavinb I'm writing a driver to interface with a custom board via rs-485. This driver is nothing more than a shared library that will be linked in the future. I added elf interpreter option to make it a executable too and now I want to add a self-test internally the library so that there is no program to do the tests.

Comment: C does not define how command-line arguments are passed to a program. The method by which a program gets the command-line arguments and, in a normal program, makes them available in the `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main`, is implementation dependent and requires each implementation to provide startup code customized for the operating system. If you want to use your own entry point, you need to research the operating system you are using and write your own code for that. You will not find the documentation for that in the C standard or the compiler documentation.

Comment: Usually, a better alternative is simple to include a `main` routine and have it call the routine you want to test.